# Do any denominations besides the United Church of God commemorate Jesus' death on a Wednesday?

Tags: life-of-jesus, denomination-survey, crucifixion, easter, chronology

Other [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3310/was-the-last-supper-not-the-passover-meal)s and [answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/248/how-long-was-jesus-in-the-tomb/3107#3107)s have established that Jesus may have actually died on a Wednesday [rather than a Friday](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3387/what-is-the-origin-of-the-good-friday-tradition).

Have any Christians [other than the United Church of God](http://www.ucg.org/doctrinal-beliefs/jesus-wasnt-crucified-friday-or-resurrected-sunday/) reached the Wednesday conclusion, so to speak?

Comment: Time is treated differently in the acient world. 3 days does not mean 72 hours or in some cases a day means a period of time.  I personally have no problem if Christ died and was burried 2.25 days and the Gospel writers exagerated the event a little. The few hours missing from thier report does not take away from the event.

Comment: It seems to me that to deny that He was in the grave for 3 full days and nights when He said He would be is to deny the only sign that He said He was giving.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Bible does not say on which day of the week Jesus was crucified. There are therefore  three views  of crucifixion day held currently: Wednesday, Thursday and Friday with Friday being the most commonly held view. **Some Christians believe Wednesday was the day of Jesus crucifixion** , and a few held the Thursday view.

That said, beside United Church of God*IA*, the [Restored Church of God](http://rcg.org/articles/ccwnof.html) also denies the 'Good Friday-Easter Sunday' chronology along with other Christian scholars of note (and presumably their followers) among whom are: [Grady Daniel](http://www.bible-truth.org/WhatDayDidChristDie.html), and [a Baptist deacon](http://www.xulonpress.com/bookstore/bookdetail.php?PB_ISBN=9781612155982); late [Charles Halff](http://www.swbcmilw.com/the-fallacies-of-easter.html), a [Messianic](http://www.cjfm.org/about-us/who-we-are/history/103-dr-charles-halff.html); and [Roy A. Reinhold](http://ad2004.com/prophecytruths/Articles/Prophecy/3days3nights.html). [This site](http://www.centuryone.com/crucifixion.html) gives an elaborate and informitive support of Wednesday conclution.